# Bluetooth: Error in firmware loading in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: bluetooth

I'm new in ubuntu.

I'm getting an error in ubuntu 14.04 in my lenovo ideapad z50-70:

```
dmesg | grep -i bluetooth
[   31.243849] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.17
[   31.243866] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   31.243873] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   31.243875] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   31.243877] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   34.700176] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   34.700187] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   34.700191] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   34.764102] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   34.764106] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   34.764114] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   39.092454] Bluetooth: Error in firmware loading err = -110,len = 448, size = 4096
[   39.092466] Bluetooth: Loading patch file failed
```

I have found a solution in askubuntu "Blacklist the ath3k module `echo "blacklist ath3k" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath3k.conf` and then `gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local` and add `modprobe ath3k` above the exit 0 line, save, exit and reboot"

But it doesn't work.

Results of cat /etc/rc.local | tail -4

# By default this script does nothing.

modprobe ath3k
exit 0

Results of

```
lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 0cf3:3004 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 5986:055e Acer, Inc 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1a2c:0027 China Resource Semico Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0101:0007  
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

@Jeremy31....after editing /etc/rc.local now i'm getting

```
dmesg | grep -i bluetooth
[   19.287994] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.17
[   19.288026] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   19.288034] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   19.288037] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   19.288041] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   23.401478] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   23.401490] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   23.401494] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   23.572239] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   23.572242] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   23.572250] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   51.045501] Bluetooth: Can't get version to change to load ram patch err
[   51.045507] Bluetooth: Loading patch file failed
```

Comment: Hi, please attach your `lsusb` output from a terminal (Ctrl + Alt + t), and update your question by [editing](http://askubuntu.com/posts/591669/edit) it.

Comment: Have you installed the package linux-firmware?  And add the results of `cat /etc/rc.local | tail -4` to your question

Comment: @P.-H.Lin........i have updated as per your advice

Comment: @Jeremy31.......i have installed firmware and i have given ur required update

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `/etc/rc.local` file and enter `sleep 20` above the `modprobe ath3k` line and reboot

Comment: @Jeremy31....after editing /etc/rc.local now i'm getting the results which i updated to original question

Comment: The only thing I can think of that might cause the new error is that it might be blocked `rfkill list bluetooth`

Comment: @Jeremy31...yes.There is a soft block on bluetooth.How to permanently remove the softblock????

Comment: `sudo rfkill unblock all` should remove all soft blocked and you might have to reboot afterwards then check `rfkill list all`

Comment: What kernel do you have? `uname -a` and what video chipset(s) do you have?  It seems this issue is fixed in kernel 3.19.1 but I don't know if it will cause problems if you have anything other than intel video